# SQLite - current_timestamp doesn't return the right hour?

Tags: sql, datetime, sqlite

In the SQLite IDE SQL window, I've written the instruction to return the the equivalence of .NET `DateTime.Now`, which is [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

Let's say it is 10:47:00 in local time, that is, GMT -4:00 (on summertime), otherwise it is GMT -5:00.

The result of my query:

```
select current_timestamp
```

returns `2010-09-23 14:47:00`, regardless of my local machine time.

**How can I make SQLite use my local time instead of GMT?**

Thanks everyone! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `select datetime(current_timestamp, 'localtime');`

You can get more info on the date/time functions [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DateAndTimeFunctions)

Comment: +1 - Very interesting! Thanks for this hint! =) I dindn't know about this, obviously. Besides, it is now returning 10:33:00, when it should return 11:33:00, because we're still on summertime in my corner of the world. Any clue?

Comment: Seems that's not implemented. See the bottom of the page at http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html for details. :)

Comment: Yes, that's also what I have read, and it seems somewhat difficult to get the correct localtime due to this change of hour (EAT). Thanks! This answers my question. =)